# Sort a DataGridView on multiple columns?

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I've searched for an example of sorting a DataGridView on multiple columns, but don't seem to be able to find an example which does what I would like.

Basically, I have a bound DataGridView control (bound to a DataTable/DataView), and the bound DataTable has two columns:- priority and date. I would like to sort by date within priority. That is, the priority column takes precendence, then its the date but both can be ascending or descending.

So, for example, I may have low priority, early date first *(order by priority asc, date asc)*, and, by clicking the date column header, switch to low priority, late date first *(order by priority asc, date desc)*. If I then click on the priority, I would like to have high priority first, then late date (the current sort order for the date column - *order by priority desc, date desc)*, but then be able to click the date column header to switch to high priority, early date *(order by priority desc, date asc)*.

Ideally, I would like sort glyphs on both columns to show ascending or descending.

Any ideas or pointers would be gratefully received.

This (see below) seems to get pretty close, but the glyphs aren't working right.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     DataSet1 dataset;

     public Form1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataset = new DataSet1(); // two columns: Priority(Int32) and date (DateTime)
        dataset.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(1, DateTime.Parse("01-jan-10"));
        dataset.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(1, DateTime.Parse("02-jan-10"));
        dataset.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(1, DateTime.Parse("03-jan-10"));
        dataset.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(2, DateTime.Parse("04-jan-10"));
        dataset.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(2, DateTime.Parse("05-jan-10"));
        dataset.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(2, DateTime.Parse("06-jan-10"));
        dataset.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(3, DateTime.Parse("07-jan-10"));
        dataset.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(3, DateTime.Parse("08-jan-10"));
        dataset.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(3, DateTime.Parse("09-jan-10"));

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.DataTable1.DefaultView;

        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
     }

     private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
     {
        DataGridViewColumn[] column = new[] { dataGridView1.Columns[0], dataGridView1.Columns[1] };

        DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell headerCell = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell;

        if (headerCell.SortGlyphDirection != SortOrder.Ascending)
           headerCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
        else
           headerCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Descending;

        String sort = column[0].DataPropertyName + " " + fnSortDirection(column[0])
                    + ", "
                    + column[1].DataPropertyName + " " + fnSortDirection(column[1]);
        dataset.DataTable1.DefaultView.Sort = sort;
        this.textBox1.Text = sort;
     }

     private String fnSortDirection(DataGridViewColumn column)
     {
        return column.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection != SortOrder.Descending ? "asc" : "desc";
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "aren't working right" with regards to the arrow glyphs? I really didn't want to take the time to write the sorting code, but I've gotten this to look right before, and it looks like you're most of the way there now.

Comment: Well... the glyph for the first column (priority) toggles between up and down, but the glyph for the second column seems to be some kind of three-state, and displays as up, nothing, nothing. I'm guessing that the DGV doesn't really like having two sorting glyphs at the same time ? I've added a third column with "normal" sorting, and that seems fine but (with the glyphs on the first two columns disappearing), but clicking the header for the 2nd column then gives me a ascending glyph on the 1st column.

Comment: Google for `MultisortDataGridView` IIRC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok.

Following from Cody's suggestions above, I now have something which seems to work as expected. I have sub-classed the HeaderCell and over-ridden the Paint method *(but cheated by setting the SortGlyphDirection immediately prior to the base.Paint)* and the DGV now paints multiple sorting glyphs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     DataSet1 dataset;

     public Form1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataset = new DataSet1(); // three columns: Priority(Int32), Date (DateTime) and Description(String)
        dataset.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(1, DateTime.Parse("01-jan-10"), "this");
        dataset.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(1, DateTime.Parse("02-jan-10"), "is");
        dataset.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(1, DateTime.Parse("03-jan-10"), "a");
        dataset.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(2, DateTime.Parse("04-jan-10"), "sample");
        dataset.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(2, DateTime.Parse("05-jan-10"), "of");
        dataset.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(2, DateTime.Parse("06-jan-10"), "the");
        dataset.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(3, DateTime.Parse("07-jan-10"), "data");
        dataset.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(3, DateTime.Parse("08-jan-10"), "in");
        dataset.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(3, DateTime.Parse("09-jan-10"), "use");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.DataTable1.DefaultView;

        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell = new MyDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell();
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderCell = new MyDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell();

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
     }

     private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
     {
        DataGridViewColumn clickedColumn = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];

        if (clickedColumn.HeaderCell is MyDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell)
        {
           DoMultiColumnSort();
        }
        else
        {
           dataGridView1.Columns.OfType<DataGridViewColumn>()
                                .Where(column => column.HeaderCell is MyDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell)
                                .ForEach(column => ((MyDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell)column.HeaderCell).SortOrderDirection = SortOrder.None);
        }

        this.textBox1.Text = dataset.DataTable1.DefaultView.Sort;
     }

     private void DoMultiColumnSort()
     {
        var sortClauses = dataGridView1.Columns.OfType<DataGridViewColumn>()
                                               .Where(column => column.HeaderCell is MyDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell)
                                               .Select(column => GetSortClause(column));

        dataset.DataTable1.DefaultView.Sort = String.Join(",", sortClauses);
     }

     private String GetSortClause(DataGridViewColumn column)
     {
        SortOrder direction = column.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection;

        if (column.HeaderCell is MyDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell)
        {
           direction = ((MyDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell)column.HeaderCell).SortOrderDirection;
        }

        return column.DataPropertyName + " " + (direction == SortOrder.Descending ? "DESC" : "ASC");
     }
  }

  public partial class MyDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell : DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell
  {
     public SortOrder SortOrderDirection { get; set; } // defaults to zero = SortOrder.None;

     protected override void Paint(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Rectangle clipBounds, System.Drawing.Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates dataGridViewElementState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
     {
        this.SortGlyphDirection = this.SortOrderDirection;
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, dataGridViewElementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
     }

     public override object Clone()
     {
        MyDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell result = (MyDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell)base.Clone();
        result.SortOrderDirection = this.SortOrderDirection;
        return result;
     }

     protected override void OnClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
     {
        this.SortOrderDirection = (this.SortOrderDirection != SortOrder.Ascending) ? SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending;
        base.OnClick(e);
     }
  }

  public static partial class Extensions
  {
     public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> value, Action<T> action) { foreach (T item in value) { action(item); } }
  }
}
```

Comment: I threw in the Linq stuff just for fun, but I'm not convinced that its a good approach (especially the "ForEach" extension). Thoughts ?

Answer (score 7):

The first time I read this, I totally missed the part about sorting by *multiple* columns simultaneously (my fault, not yours; the question was perfectly clear).

If that's the case, you are going to have to write the code that handles this yourself. The provided `DataGridView` control doesn't support multi-column sorting by default. Fortunately, others have already done a lot of the work to implement this for you. Here are a few samples:

- [DataGridView Multi-column Sort](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/multicolumn_sort.aspx) (CodeProject)
- [How To Allow To Sort By Multiple Columns in Custom Data Binding](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/Multiple_columns_sorting.aspx) (CodeProject)

Alternatively, if you bind your `DataGridView` to a data source, that data source can be sorted on multiple columns and the `DataGridView` control will respect that sorting. Any data source that implements `IBindingListView` and exposes a `Sort` property will work for multi-column sorting.

However, regardless of the route that you choose to enable multi-column sorting, you aren't going to have much success in coercing the `DataGridView` to display the sort arrow glyph on multiple columns. The easiest solution here is to custom draw only the column headers to provide your own sort glyph.

To do this, attach a handler to the [`DataGridView.CellPainting` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting.aspx) and check for a `RowIndex` of -1 (indicating a column header). There's a full sample of owner-drawn column headers [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/GradientColumnheader.aspx). I strongly recommend sticking with the conventional arrow icon, but once you go this route, the options are truly unlimited. You can make your column headers look like anything you want, and even indicate the relative weight of each column in the sort order using different icons.

You can also choose to derive a new class from [`DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumnheadercell.aspx) and override its [`Paint` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumnheadercell.paint.aspx). This is probably a cleaner, more object-oriented way of accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: Cody, Many thanks for taking the time to suggest a solution - it is greatly appreciated. I went with the HeaderCell/OnPaint method, but might investigate your other suggestions as well.

Answer (score 5):

When **DataGridView** binds to the **DataSource** (*DataView, BindingSource, Table, DataSet+"tablename"*) in all cases it refere to the **DataView**. Get reference to this DataView and set **Sort** (and **Filter**) as you wish:

```
DataView dv = null;
CurrencyManager cm = (CurrencyManager)(dgv.BindingContext[dgv.DataSource, dgv.DataMember]);

if (cm.List is BindingSource)
{
    // In case of BindingSource it may be chain of BindingSources+relations
    BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)cm.List;
    while (bs.List is BindingSource)
    { bs = bs.List as BindingSource; }

    if (bs.List is DataView)
    { dv = bs.List as DataView; }
}
else if (cm.List is DataView)
{
    // dgv bind to the DataView, Table or DataSet+"tablename"
    dv = cm.List as DataView;
}

if (dv != null)
{
    dv.Sort = "somedate desc, firstname";
    // dv.Filter = "lastname = 'Smith' OR lastname = 'Doe'";

    //  You can Set the Glyphs something like this:
    int somedateColIdx = 5;    // somedate
    int firstnameColIdx = 3;   // firstname
    dgv.Columns[somedateColIdx].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Descending;
    dgv.Columns[firstnameColIdx].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
}
```

Note: **Column names used in Sort and Filter correspond to the column names in DataTable**,
Column names in DataGridView are the underlying data property names used for binding (property names for classes, column names for DataTables, etc.).  You can get column name used in DataView like this:

```
string colName = dgv.Columns[colIdx].DataPropertyName
```

Depends of how do you want to track sorted columns (colSequence, colName, asc/desc, dgvColIdx) you may decide how to build Sort and Filter expression and set the SortGlyph in dgv (I made hardcode for simplicity).

Answer (score 2):

I have never answered a question on here, so I apologize if the format is incorrect,  but I found an answer to this question which may be simpler for future visitors. (See http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/datagridview-glyphs.3145090/ )

```
Dim dictionarySortColumns As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)


Private Sub DataGridViewFileLoader_Sorted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridViewFileLoader.Sorted


    Dim dv As New DataView(dataSetLoadScreener.Tables(0))
    Dim columnHeader As String = DataGridViewFileLoader.SortedColumn.Name

    Dim sortDirection As Integer = DataGridViewFileLoader.SortOrder
    Dim sortcode As String = ""
    Dim sortOrder As String = ""

    If sortDirection = 1 Then
        sortOrder = "ASC"
    Else
        sortOrder = "DESC"
    End If

    If dictionarySortColumns.ContainsKey(columnHeader) Then
        dictionarySortColumns.Remove(columnHeader)
    End If

    sortcode = columnHeader + " " + sortOrder

    For Each colHeader As String In dictionarySortColumns.Keys
        If dictionarySortColumns(colHeader) = 1 Then
            sortOrder = "ASC"
        Else
            sortOrder = "DESC"
        End If

        sortcode = sortcode + "," + colHeader + " " + sortOrder

    Next

    dictionarySortColumns.Add(columnHeader, sortDirection)

    dv.Sort = sortcode
    DataGridViewFileLoader.DataSource = Nothing
    DataGridViewFileLoader.DataSource = dv

    formatDataGridViewFileLoader()

End Sub

 Private Sub DataGridViewFileLoader_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewFileLoader.CellPainting
    Dim sOrder As System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder

    For Each key As String In dictionarySortColumns.Keys
        If dictionarySortColumns(key) = 1 Then
            sOrder = Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending
        Else
            sOrder = Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Descending
        End If

        DataGridViewFileLoader.Columns(key).HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = sOrder
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this would help Black Light with their issue?

Comment: well, I understood Black Light's question to be that they want to have primary and secondary sorting on columns that are bound to a dataview, and then to have glyphs on each header that says in which direction it is sorting. This code gives priority in the order that the columns are sorted, with the most recent column to be sorted having highest priority. It also shows direction glyphs on each columns.

Comment: I created an CellPainting event handler and set the SortGlyphDirection as shown in the sample code. When I sort by one column the column header flickers on and off. When I sort by two or more columns the column header's sort glyph is displayed only on the last (right-most) sorted column.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that works like google spreadsheets - clicking on each column header sorts by that column, and clicking again on the column swaps the search direction. Furthermore, it searches in reverse order of the history of how you clicked on the columns, i.e. if you click on column D then B then C then A, on that last click it will sort by columns A, C, B, D, and in the direction for each that it searched on when you most recently clicked on that column.

It relies on these features built-in to the DataGridView:

- If DataGridView has a DataView as its DataSource, then setting the Sort string for that DataView causes an immediate sort of the DataView, and that sort shows right away in the bound DataGridView control
- The Sort string can include multiple columns, each of which can be indicated to sort ASC or DESC
- When you set the Sort string of the DataView (thereby causing it to sort), the DataGridView to which it is bound will add the appropriate up-down glyph automagically, based on the first item (name and direction) in your sort string

We start with a sorter object:

```cs
internal class Sorter 
{
    internal readonly string ColumnName;
    internal bool IsAscending;

    internal Sorter(string columnName, bool isAscending)
    {
        this.ColumnName = columnName;
        this.IsAscending = isAscending;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {  // For equivalence, compare column name only (not object ref or sort order)
        if (other == null) { return false; }
        if (other.GetType() != typeof(Sorter)) { return false; }
        return this.ColumnName == ((Sorter)other).ColumnName;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    { // required if we have overridden Equals
        return this.ColumnName.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.ColumnName + (this.IsAscending ? " ASC" : " DESC");
    }
}
```

And then collect our Sorter objects into a Sorters class:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

internal class Sorters : List<Sorter>
{
    internal void BringColumnToFrontOfSortingOrder(Sorter sorter)
    {
        if (this.Contains<Sorter>(sorter))
        {
            this.Remove(sorter); // remove it from where it is
        }
        // put it at the start
        this.Insert(0, sorter);
    }

    // Returns a DataView sorting string like "ColName1 ASC, ColName2 DESC" etc
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        foreach (Sorter sorter in this)
        {
            if (s.Length > 0) { s.Append(", "); }
            s.Append(sorter.ToString());
        }
        return s.ToString();
    }
}
```

And I make my own MultiSortingDataGridView class, deriving from DataGridView, with an overridden Sort method that keeps track of which columns you clicked on, and causes a sort of the DataView that is the bound DataSource of my grid, based on the history of your column sorting clicks:

```cs
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;

public class MultiSortingDataGridView : DataGridView // derive from DataGridView and extend it
{
    private Sorters _sorters = new Sorters(); // keeping track of what column(s) we have searched by

    // override the regular search with our super duper multi-column search
    public override void Sort(DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn, ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        Sorter sorter = new Sorter(dataGridViewColumn.Name, direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        this._sorters.BringColumnToFrontOfSortingOrder(sorter);

        // Get the data view that is our data source
        DataView vw = (DataView)this.DataSource;

        // When you set the Sort property, it causes it to sort, and happily it sets
        // the up/down glyph of the column that corresponds to your first sort-by item.
        vw.Sort = this._sorters.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then in my form, I make sure that I use a MultiSortingDataGridView control (as above) instead of the regular DataGridView, and I set its data source like this:

```cs
DataTable tbl = SomeMethodForGettingMyTabularData(); // instantiate a data table with the data you want to show
DataView vw = new DataView(tbl); // make a data view from it
this.dgv.DataSource = vw; // bind the view as data source to my MultiSortingDataGridView control
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I could find, tested and works for vb.net (but not sure if this also works for c# and if it still works if you use a datatable), is to just first sort on the second column you want to sort, and then the main column.

Here's what that could would look like:

```
        Me.dgv.Sort(Me.dgv.Columns(1), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
        Me.dgv.Sort(Me.dgv.Columns(2), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

This will result in a DataGridView, sorted by column 2 ascended order, then column 1 ascended order.