# Sort Column Based on Similar ID

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview, datatable

I have this `DataGridView` using C# in the .Net Framework, and I am wondering if someone can help me sort the `Age` column based on the same `ID`.

My `DataGridView` looks like this:

[image: initialTable]

But when I used this:

```
this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns["Age"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

It sorts the whole `Age` column, which I do not like. It means the data on `ID` will look like something like this, and sorted differently:

[image: tableresult]

My question is there a possible way to only sort within the same ID?

Comment: I believe you are looking for multi-column sort, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646873/sort-a-datagridview-on-multiple-columns).

Comment: where did you get the data provided in your sample? is it from the database? or default data in your system?

Comment: i can suggest that if it is in the database then sort it there before placing it in datagridview, but if it is in the system default value then sort is using 2 datagridview. in 1st datagrid where data is stored used loop where id is same and age is acs or desc base on your wants. then place it to the final datagrid 1 by 1. then use the final datagridview as your final output. hope this help.

Comment: You're asking to sort the ID column then the Age column. Follow Clay's suggestion.